# Not able to set ElasticSearch cluster. Getting RemoteTransportException

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to establish elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes.

```
My node settings:
cluster.name: ControlElasticSearch

  node.name: VinodNode
  node.master: true
  node.data: true
  network.host: 132.186.102.84

 discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["132.186.102.49","132.186.189.127","132.186.102.84"]

 discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

 When i restart my elasticsearch, i am getting **RemoteTransportException**.



    [2017-05-29T17:33:58,374][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [VinodNode] failed to send join request to master 
     [{DivyaNode}{LKhUGAEXTzO-ZcglRYC_yQ}{YO0qeSh8QMWclmYcSCNyMg}{132.186.102.49}{132.186.102.49:9300}], 
     reason [RemoteTransportException[[DivyaNode][132.186.102.49:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]];
     nested: ConnectTransportException[[VinodNode][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]];
     nested: IOException[Connection refused: no further information: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:9300];
     nested: IOException[Connection refused: no further information]; ]


 May i please know what might be the reason. If i just work with single node, it works. when i am trying to set up as cluster, i am facing this issue.
```

I am able to ping the machines and all the machines are in the same network.

Comment: What version of ES are you using? As per logs `VinodNode` was trying to establish transport connection with localhost IP address `127.0.0.1:9300`. So check whether you are configured properly.

Comment: I am using almost latest version.  Dont have access to thr code now.. Wil check and update tomorrow.. I think i habe downloaded elasticsearch about 2 weeks ago.. Why its pointing to 9300

Comment: To divya node also its pointing to 9300.. Divya node elasticsearch is up snd running on 9200.. I have provided my elasticsearch.yml configuration in the question it self.. There is nothing more than that.. May i please know why its happening.. Any clue

Comment: Vinodnode is the local node..and 132.186.102.84 is its ip.

Comment: I was going through some links and found that 9200 is for REST and 9300 is required for node communication.. Now the question is to find out if 9300 port is blocked/disabled.

Comment: Can anyone please update the reason for getting remotetransportexception..

Comment: Whenever one of your nodes in ES cluster is unable to communicate with other nodes through Transport port you will get `RemoteTransportException`. Please check firewall in all nodes to open the port `9300`. Also make sure `VinodeNode` is using `132.186.102.84` for `network.host`

Comment: Hi avr.. Will try to check if firewall for 9300 port.. Thanks for input.. May i have ur mail id?